# Using GDB to debug a process

Tags: c, process, gdb

I am using gdb to debug a process which runs in my m/c. I have attched the process to gdb and using breakpoints at various places to flow through the code. However, before I can reach anything useful, the process gets killed by the SIGPIPE signal. Is there any way I can prevent this using gdb so that I can continue my debugging session using GDB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

handle SIGPIPE nostop

[Debugging with GDB - Signals](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gdb-5.0/html_node/gdb_38.html)